# How to activate Windows 10 with Windows 7 Key

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I am trying to activate my **clean Windows 10 (Pro)** installation. I was using Windows 7 (Home Premium) on my 2011 Lenovo IdeaPad Y580. After upgrading *the normal way* failed I had to create a bootable USB-Stick and install Windows 10 manually.

If I try to activate with my Windows 7 Key it says that this edition is **not suitable with the given key**. Do I need to use Windows 10 Home Edition or is there another way to activate my current installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be on the November update of Windows 10 to directly use a Windows 7 product key, and you must use a product key from the [appropriate edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications?tduid=(1b27e84a1782eee195d1dece21c4d2e6)(259740)(2542549)(d_wp)()):

[image: Windows 10 Upgrade Editions]

As you're using Windows 10 Pro, you would need a Windows 7 Professional or Windows 7 Ultimate key to activate with. You will need to purchase a valid key, or install Windows 10 Home instead.

Comment: you should be right, the key is for Windows 7 Home Premium and I installed Windows 10 Pro according to your link. Is there an easy way to downgrade to Windows 10 Home apart from another clean installation? Or upgrade the key somehow?

Comment: I'm afraid a clean installation is the only method I know of, I did just do a quick search for you but I don't think it's possible. Interestingly there was an unofficial tool for Windows 7 that would do just that, but I can't see anything for 10, and honestly I wouldn't want to risk it anyway. I'm sorry that's probably not the answer you were hoping for!

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't spend a lot of time with the new Windows yet so it wouldn't be a great loss.